# Calling GET_LIST in LOV Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I just want to call the GEt list in LOV field. what trigger should I use and how I call get list with LOV?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `get_list` in Forms (at least, not in any version I know).

Anyway: I'd suggest you to

- create a **Record Group** query
- create a List of Values which uses query you create previously
- attach that LoV to an item

That's the way I prefer; it is simple enough, works well, and Forms knows how to invoke it using keyboard shortcut.